# Select data frame values row-wise using a variable of column names

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
dframe = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))
#   x y
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6
```

And a vector of column names, one per row of the data frame:

`colname = c('x', 'y', 'x')`

For each row of the data frame, I would like to select the value from the corresponding column in the vector. Something similar to `dframe[, colname]` but for each row.

Thus, I want to obtain `c(1, 5, 3)` (i.e. row 1: col "x"; row 2: col "y"; row 3: col "x")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favourite old matrix-indexing will take care of this. Just pass a 2-column matrix with the respective row/column index:

```
rownames(dframe) <- seq_len(nrow(dframe))
dframe[cbind(rownames(dframe),colname)]
#[1] 1 5 3
```

Or, if you don't want to add rownames:

```
dframe[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dframe)), match(colname,names(dframe)))]
#[1] 1 5 3
```

Comment: @Onyambu - I assure you that `dframe[cbind(rownames(dframe),colname)]` will not work unless I force the rownames into it.

Comment: @Onyambu - there is a slight difference between the default row.names and explicitly adding `1:n` - see `row.names = c(NA,-3L)` vs `row.names = c(NA, 3L)` when `dput`-ing before and after adding `rownames`.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `mapply` to pass  arguments for `rownumber` (of `dframe`) and vector for column name (for each row) to return specific column value.

The solution using `mapply` can be as:

```
dframe = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6))
colname = c('x', 'y', 'x')

mapply(function(x,y)dframe[x,y],1:nrow(dframe),  colname)

#[1] 1 5 3
```

Although, the next option may not be very intuitive but if someone wants a solution in `dplyr` chain then a way using `gather` can be as:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(colname = c('x', 'y', 'x'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  left_join(dframe %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
              gather(colname, value, -rowname), 
            by = c("rowname", "colname" )) %>%
  select(rowname, value)

#   rowname value
# 1       1     1
# 2       2     5
# 3       3     3
```