# Coalesce column values based on mapping to a vector of values

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

If I have the following two objects:

```
> set.seed(100)
> lookup <- sample(1:3, 20, replace=T)
> lookup
[1] 2 3 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 1 3
```

and

```
> tb <- tibble(A=runif(20,0,1), B=runif(20,0,1), C= runif(20,0,1))
> tb

> tb
# A tibble: 20 × 3
       A     B      C
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 0.770 0.780 0.456 
 2 0.882 0.884 0.445 
 3 0.549 0.208 0.245 
 4 0.278 0.307 0.694 
 5 0.488 0.331 0.412 
 6 0.929 0.199 0.328 
 7 0.349 0.236 0.573 
 8 0.954 0.275 0.967 
 9 0.695 0.591 0.662 
10 0.889 0.253 0.625 
11 0.180 0.123 0.857 
12 0.629 0.230 0.775 
13 0.990 0.598 0.834 
14 0.130 0.211 0.0915
15 0.331 0.464 0.460 
16 0.865 0.647 0.599 
17 0.778 0.961 0.920 
18 0.827 0.676 0.983 
19 0.603 0.445 0.0378
20 0.491 0.358 0.578
```

How do I use `lookup` to select the value of the corresponding row/column from `tb`?

i.e.

- if the first element of `lookup` = 1 then I would like to select the value in A from the first row of `tb`
- if the second element of `lookup` = 2 then I would like to select the value in B from the second row of `tb`

So I should end up with a 1d vector that is the same size as `lookup`. It will look like this:

```
> new data
> [1] 0.780 0.445 0.208 0.694 0.488 ... 0.578
```

Thanks!

Comment: thanks will edit!

Comment: brucezepplin, the use of `set.seed` controls all subsequent randomness. The point is that you need to call `set.seed(100)`, and then do your random stuff. In this case, `lookup` starts with `c(2,3,2,3,1,2,...)`. This also affects `tb`, so ideally you should run `set.seed(100)`, `lookup <- ...`, and `tb <- ...`. Intermingling code that does not use randomness will not affect randomness, but of course if they are printing/using the random data, they will also need to be rerun.

Comment: hi both - have sorted now - re-ran after setting seed. schoolboy error

Comment: Related: [Select data frame values row-wise using a variable of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093685/select-data-frame-values-row-wise-using-a-variable-of-column-names) and [Index a data frame row-by-row using column names selected from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056799/index-a-data-frame-row-by-row-using-column-names-selected-from-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.frame` (but not `tibble` or `data.table`) supports indexing on a matrix, so with this data,

```r
set.seed(42)
lookup <- sample(1:3, 20, replace=T)
lookup
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 3
tb <- tibble(A=runif(20,0,1), B=runif(20,0,1), C= runif(20,0,1))
head(tb)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#       A     B      C
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 0.514 0.958 0.189 
# 2 0.390 0.888 0.271 
# 3 0.906 0.640 0.828 
# 4 0.447 0.971 0.693 
# 5 0.836 0.619 0.241 
# 6 0.738 0.333 0.0430
```

We can do

```r
as.data.frame(tb)[cbind(seq_along(lookup), lookup)]
#  [1] 0.514211784 0.390203467 0.905738131 0.446969628 0.618838207 0.333427211 0.346748248 0.388108283 0.479398564
# [10] 0.197410342 0.832916080 0.007334147 0.171264330 0.261087964 0.514412935 0.581604003 0.157905208 0.037431033
# [19] 0.973539914 0.775823363
```

A less-efficient method can be done without `as.data.frame`:

```r
mapply(`[[`, list(tb), seq_along(lookup), lookup)
#  [1] 0.514211784 0.390203467 0.905738131 0.446969628 0.618838207 0.333427211 0.346748248 0.388108283 0.479398564
# [10] 0.197410342 0.832916080 0.007334147 0.171264330 0.261087964 0.514412935 0.581604003 0.157905208 0.037431033
# [19] 0.973539914 0.775823363
## also works with `list(as.data.table(tb))`
```

Though it does take a big hit in performance (not a surprise):

```r
bench::mark(
  sindri_baldur1 = unlist(tb, use.names = FALSE)[seq_along(lookup) + (lookup - 1L)*nrow(tb)], 
  sindri_baldur2 = unlist(tb)[seq_along(lookup) + (lookup - 1L)*nrow(tb)], 
  base = as.data.frame(tb)[cbind(seq_along(lookup), lookup)], 
  mapply = mapply(`[[`, list(tb), seq_along(lookup), lookup), 
  paulsmith2 = {
tb %>% 
  mutate(lookup = lookup) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(new = c_across(A:C)[lookup]) %>% 
  pull(new)
},
  check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 5 x 13
#   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory  time   gc    
#   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>  <list> <list>
# 1 sindri_baldur1    4.5us    5.3us   159430.      736B    15.9   9999     1     62.7ms <NULL> <Rprof~ <benc~ <tibb~
# 2 sindri_baldur2   13.2us   14.7us    56723.    1.44KB     0    10000     0    176.3ms <NULL> <Rprof~ <benc~ <tibb~
# 3 base             78.3us   91.6us     7334.      944B     8.59  3414     4    465.5ms <NULL> <Rprof~ <benc~ <tibb~
# 4 mapply          612.4us 779.45us      942.      720B     6.39   442     3    469.4ms <NULL> <Rprof~ <benc~ <tibb~
# 5 paulsmith2       4.37ms   5.85ms      147.    20.3KB     6.51    68     3    461.1ms <NULL> <Rprof~ <benc~ <tibb~
```

(I have to use `check=FALSE` to work with the names introduced in `sindri_baldur2`, otherwise all results are numerically identical.)

Comment: Matrix subsetting is very undervalued I think. Also could you add my solution to the benchmark?

Comment: I was already doing that :-). (Your method ***ROCKS***.)

Comment: (Sorry @PaulSmith, it's not looking good ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could:

```
unlist(tb, use.names = FALSE)[seq_along(lookup) + (lookup - 1L)*nrow(tb)]

#  [1] 0.78035851 0.44541398 0.20771390 0.69435071 0.48830599 0.19867907 0.23569430 0.96699908 0.59132105
# [10] 0.25339065 0.85665304 0.22990589 0.59757529 0.09151028 0.45952549 0.59939816 0.91972191 0.67639817
# [19] 0.60332436 0.57793740
```

You could also `use.names` and keep track of the original location:

```
unlist(tb)[seq_along(lookup) + (lookup - 1L)*nrow(tb)] |> head()
#        B1        C2        B3        C4        A5        B6 
# 0.7803585 0.4454140 0.2077139 0.6943507 0.4883060 0.1986791
```

Comment: I think this should be formalized as `inverse.arrayInd` or similar :-)

Comment: @r2evans I fail to think of any practical application

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```r
tb$lookup <- lookup
tb$new <- apply(tb, 1, function(x) x[x[4]])
new <- tb$new
new

#>  [1] 0.78035851 0.44541398 0.20771390 0.69435071 0.48830599 0.19867907
#>  [7] 0.23569430 0.96699908 0.59132105 0.25339065 0.85665304 0.22990589
#> [13] 0.59757529 0.09151028 0.45952549 0.59939816 0.91972191 0.67639817
#> [19] 0.60332436 0.57793740
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(100)

lookup <- sample(1:3, 20, replace=T)
tb <- tibble(A=runif(20,0,1), B=runif(20,0,1), C= runif(20,0,1))

tb %>% 
  mutate(lookup = lookup) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(new = c_across(A:C)[lookup]) %>% 
  pull(new)

#>  [1] 0.78035851 0.44541398 0.20771390 0.69435071 0.48830599 0.19867907
#>  [7] 0.23569430 0.96699908 0.59132105 0.25339065 0.85665304 0.22990589
#> [13] 0.59757529 0.09151028 0.45952549 0.59939816 0.91972191 0.67639817
#> [19] 0.60332436 0.57793740
```